# windows log path for running Spark HistoryServer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have followed instruction on spark website for configuring pySpark HistoryServer locally on Windows but cannot get past this error when I run: spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
:  **Log directory specified does not exist: file:/tmp/spark-events Did you configure the correct one through spark.history.fs.logDirectory?**

```
spark-defaults.conf has:
spark.eventLog.enabled             true
spark.history.fs.logDirectory      file:/tmp/spark-events
spark.eventLog.dir                 file:/tmp/spark-events
```

I can get pyspark to run and I can successfully submit .py script with spark-submit

I have created the directory /tmp/spark-events in both SPARK_HOME and SPARK_HOME/bin because i'm not exactly sure where "file:/tmp/spark-events" should actually located. Where exactly on Windows do I need to create this directory "tmp/spark-events" so it can be found?  Am I missing anything else?  Also, even if I change the paths in the .conf file it still gives error saynig can't find tmp/spark-events so it's like it's not even using the values in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose where `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` points to! In your case, it should be a windows path. The idea is the following:

- You make a directory wherever you would like it, with the proper permissions on there (more info on that [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#event-logging))
- When that is done, you should be able to start up your history server, with `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` pointing to that one directory you made. This is not a relative path w.r.t. your `$SPARK_HOME` env variable, but an absolute path.

  - If that works, you should see a rather uninteresting screen (the default port is 18080 so locally you should visit `localhost:18080`): since none of your applications have written to your directory yet you will see an empty History Server screen
- If you want to make use of the history server, you have to make your apps write to the eventlog directory you made. That can be done by adding `--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=<your-dir>` to your spark-submit call.

  - If that was successful, you should see a file in your log directory you made!
- Have a look at your History server (by default on `localhost:18080`). You should see your application's logs in there!

Hope this helps :)